# Dynamic data based on country

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm working on a solution for a customer where the administrator for each country will define things to be talked about with the customer, call it a visitation guide for meetings.

My question is:

How can I use one entity to support multiple types of data.

I was thinking about hooking the entity up on either the business unit or a security role, and have one line for each country, and then restrict it to only be editable for the country administrator maybe using som security profile.

Is this possible?

Any approaches or rethinking are welcome.

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 1):

Make this entity invisible to "country administrators" by default and manually share each instance with an appropriate administrator[s].

Answer (score 1):

A key factor here is whether you want each admin to see the other admin's fields, and whether any other admins may be in the position to edit fields that are out of their usual line of editing.

You have two options really;

1) Use separate forms for specific teams where each teams has one of those administrators, so that each team sees a different and bespoke perspective of the entity itself. This way as far as other admins are concerned, the only fields that exist are their own because they only see the relevant fields on the form.

2) Use the same form but apply field security for either teams or specific users. That way the other admins would know about each other's fields, but you can vary permissions based on who is viewing the form.

One thing you may also want to consider here is the Security Role and what records they have viability of, particular if you're going to look at the first option.